# Localizing CoreSearchResults Web Part with XSL

Tags: search, xslt

We are using custom XSL to transform the search results. There is a couple of labels in the custom search results and these need to be localized when user changes language. [This article](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/xsltlistviewwebpart-contentbyquerywebpa.html) explains how is that is with CQWP but it seems CoreResults WebPart does not use dsQueryResponse and I have no idea how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Managed to solve this](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2012/06/localizing-coresearchresults-web-part-with-xslt/), here is what you need to do:

- A Resource file (e.g. *YourResourceFileName.resx*) must be placed in inetpub directory e.g. *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources*
- Parameter binding must be created for each resource you plan to use e.g.

  <ParameterBinding Name="ParameterName" Location="Resource(YourResourceFileName,NameOfResourceToBeExtracted)">
- Use the following syntax to display the value:

  <xsl:value-of select="$ParameterName"/>